# How to sort glob.glob containing numbers?

Tags: python, sorting, glob, natural-sort

Doing

```
glob.glob('/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log*')
```

gives an unsorted list such as `['....76.gz', '....16.gz', '....46.gz', ...]`. Also,

```
sorted(glob.glob('/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log*'))
```

gives

```
other_vhosts_access.log
other_vhosts_access.log.1
other_vhosts_access.log.10.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.11.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.12.gz
...
other_vhosts_access.log.19.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.2.gz
```

**How to have a better sort?**  .log, .log.1, .log.2.gz, ..., .log.9.gz, .log.10.gz, ...

Comment: You can create your own sort key function and pass it to sorted, and the sort key could pull out the number, and return it as an int.

Comment: @RufusVS Yes, with `sorted(..., key=...)`, but I'm more looking for a general solution not harcoded for each situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, perhaps something like this will do.  This pulls the first sequence of digits found between decimal points or at the end of the file and uses the value as the primary sort key, and the full file name for secondary.

```
file_list = """
other_vhosts_access.log
other_vhosts_access.log.1
other_vhosts_access.log.10.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.11.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.12.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.19.gz
other_vhosts_access.log.2.gz
""".strip().split()

import re

re_num = r"\.(\d+)(\.|$)"

def sort_key(file_name):
    match=re.search(re_num,file_name)
    if match is None:
        return(0,file_name)
    else:
        return(int(match.group(1)),file_name)
    
print(*sorted(file_list,key=sort_key),sep='\n')
```

Comment: Isn't there a generaly way without hardcoding this regex search?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "general" way.  Every way will have to include a way to parse the file names with some kind of rule to establish sortation order.

Comment: Isn't there a general "natural sort" way to do it @RufusVS? Here is how it works with `/bin/ls`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33909/list-files-sorted-numerically/33913#33913

Comment: There are much better (more general) solutions in the link specified in the closed note and other answer.  Oh! you posted that answer!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Is there a built in function for string natural sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort/16090640#16090640), here is a one-liner solution:

```
natsort = lambda s: [int(t) if t.isdigit() else t.lower() for t in re.split('(\d+)', s)]

sorted(glob.glob('/var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log*'), key=natsort)
```

Comment: This is essentially a copy of that answer. Good case for closing as a duplicate IMO

Comment: Thank you for linking the duplicate @PranavHosangadi. Note: I clearly cited the original question, I didn't do it for rep, but just for completeness, so that anyone can find the solution quickly without reading the many answers there. Not sure a downvote is really useful here ;)

Comment: I love one-liners!  I'll have to learn about `re.split` now!